# Process and clean a huge .tar file with millions of small XML files

Tags: python, bigdata

I have one huge `.tar` file (~700GB) which includes millions of small XML files (<1MB each). The dataset has a lot of unnecessary information that I don't need in the project I am working on. What I try to do is to read all those XML files, remove the info that I don't need and save the new dataset as a CSV (which I expect to be around a dozen of GBs).

I tried to unpack the `.tar` file, to read and clean each of them with Python, but after 24hours of unpacking, I wasn't even at half of the process.

I used this command

`tar -xvf myfile.tar`

How I should proceed with this? What is the fastest way to read, clean and save the new data?

Comment: Which tools you prefer?

Comment: I prefer Python, but if there is any other (faster way), I am open for suggestion